# xcode file mark boxes in Project Navigator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, project-navigator

What are these?
[image]

specifically the A/M/? marks near some of the files? what each letter means?

It's a project which I imported from previous xcode version (and iOS 4). The projects compiles alright though. My new storyboard/iOS 5 projects do not show these marks. What do they represent and how can I set/reset these?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are source control management (SCM) status boxes, from git or subversion as Ell has mentioned.

The specific statuses:

A - added to the local repository (new file that doesn't exist in the remote repository yet)

M - Modified (existing file that has been changed)

? - File that exists on the file system but hasn't been added to the repository, locally or remotely. You can add it by right clicking on the file, source control, add.

Comment: mmm.. so what's the difference between 'A' and '?'?

also something odd:
when I press 'add' on a ? marked file it changes to 'A', when I select Update/Commit I get "The repository "AppName" could not be reached." error...

Comment: The difference between ? and A is that ? has not even been marked for addition locally, which means when you commit it wouldn't go to the repository. A, however, has been marked, so it would go to the repository. I'm not sure why you would get that as I don't know the specifics of your repository configuration, but that may be better as a separate question.

Comment: Modified my answer a bit to reflect the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

There symbols represent SCM status, either from git or subversion. If you're not using SCM, you can ignore them.