# How to associate .xib with MasterViewController .h & .m

Tags: xcode, xib, nib, connection

I have two *MasterViewControllers*, one is called "`.h`" and one is "`.m`".

I manually created a .xib to do the interface for the app but when I try to connect the code to the interface buttons I created it doesn't see them.

The MasterViewControllers have the letter "*M*" next to them, but the xib has the letter "*A*" next to it.

I can't find out how to change is.

If I can change this to "*M*", will this fix the connections not showing up?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Select your XIB, then select "File's Owner", and in the "Identity Inspector," select the Class file you wish to associate with it in the "Class" drop down menu. (see screenshots)

(BTW, a 'Class" means *both* the .m and the .h)

[image]

[image]

The letter next the file name you refer to has to do with source control. It has nothing to do with what xib is associated with what view controller or wether or not it is the MainViewController. See this question for more info: [xcode file mark boxes in Project Navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8978161/1126783)